# Why do I have double print in loop while

Tags: c

I have a loop while and inside `printf("entre r 3 for rock or c 1 for scissor or p 2 for paper :\n");`
When I execute the program the first step everything write but the second  step in the loop the program prints double  `printf("entre r 3 for rock or c 1 for scissor or p 2 for paper :\n");`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int choicep(char choice){
    if (choice=='c')
    {
        return 1;
    }else if (choice=='p')
    {
        return 2;
    }
    else if(choice=='r'){
        return 3;
    }
}

int main(){
    srand(time(NULL));
    char player choice;
    int playerscore=0,computer=0;
    int choice,computer choice;
    while (playerscore != 3 && computer!= 3)
    {
        printf("entre r 3 for rock or c 1 for scissors or p 2 for paper :\n");
        scanf("%c",&player choice);
        choice = choice p(player choice);
        computer choice = (rand() % 3 )+1;
        if (computer choice==1)
        {
            switch (choice)
            {
            case 1:
                printf("draw !\n");
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("computer win \n");
                break;
            case 3:
                printf("player win \n");
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
        if (computerchoice==2)
        {
            switch (choice)
            {
            case 2:
                printf("draw !\n");
                break;
            case 3:
                printf("computer win\n ");
                break;
            case 1:
                printf("player win ");
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
        if (computer choice==3)//r
        {
            switch (choice)
            {
            case 3:
                printf("draw !\n");
                break;
            case 1:
                printf("computer win \n");
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("player win\n ");
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to create game rock paper scissors.

Comment: This is the perfect time to learn how to [*debug*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) your programs. For example, by using a [*debugger*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) you can step through your code line by line while monitoring variables and their values. That should hopefully help you understand what's happening.

Comment: And please make sure you copy-pate the correct program to show us. The code you show won't even build.

Comment: @Abdel djalil Boulebbina What is that char player choice;?

Comment: @Abdel djalil Boulebbina Using the return value of the function choicep can invoke undefined behavior because it returns a value not in all paths of execution.

Comment: @Abdel djalil Boulebbina And instead of  scanf("%c",&player choice); (supposing that the variable is written correctly) you have to write scanf(" %c",&player choice);. Pay attention to the leading space in the format string. It allows to skip for example the new line character '\n' that corresponds to the pressed key Enter.

Comment: You are reading the input char by char, what you think will be read if you type `1` followed by `<RET>`? Add some logic to ignore end of line chars.

Comment: You lost some `_` in your variable names during copy&paste.

Answer (score 0):

It's doing that because its looping round and not able to find an answer for choicep(player_choice). Why is it doing that?

Let's see what happens if i put in '123456' for example:

[image]

I've got it to print the ascii value of the character put in player_choice. Seems like it is going through every number i put in and then ends on ascii 10, which is the ascii value for a newline (\n). So, what happens is your program fills player_choice with the character, then loops round, prints the "entre r 3" line and then when it gets to scanf it fills player_choice with the next character. This is because scanf uses the input buffer, which won't automatically get cleared when scanf works, you have to do it yourself somehow.

So ultimately the issue isn't to do with printf, but scanf and printing twice was a symptom of it.

One way to fix it is by putting a space before %c in scanf as shown in your modified code below:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int choicep(char choice){
    if (choice=='c')
    {
        return 1;
    }else if (choice=='p')
    {
        return 2;
    }
    else if(choice=='r'){
        return 3;
    }
}

int main(){
    srand(time(NULL));
    char player_choice;
    int playerscore=0, computer=0;
    int choice, computer_choice;
    while (playerscore != 3 && computer!= 3)
    {
        printf("entre r for rock or c for scissors or p for paper :\n");
        scanf(" %c",&player_choice);
        choice = choicep(player_choice);
        computer_choice = (rand() % 3 )+1;
        if (computer_choice==1)
        {
            switch (choice)
            {
            case 1:
                printf("draw !\n");
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("computer win \n");
                break;
            case 3:
                printf("player win \n");
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
        else if (computer_choice==2) // Added else to make intent clearer
        {
            switch (choice)
            {
            case 2:
                printf("draw !\n");
                break;
            case 3:
                printf("computer win\n ");
                break;
            case 1:
                printf("player win \n");
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
        else if (computer_choice==3)//r
        {
            switch (choice)
            {
            case 3:
                printf("draw !\n");
                break;
            case 1:
                printf("computer win \n");
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("player win\n ");
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This will work to stop scanf reading that pesky newline. The reasons why are a bit more complex and have to do with the way scanf works, which uses a format string to match the format of the user input. By adding a space, you tell scanf to ignroe all whitespace before, which includes \n. This gets matched to the input the next time round, so it ignores the \n and just waits for you input.

Alternatively, you can manually loop through scanf each to untill you get to \n which will prevent the user entering multiple numbers.

ps. You may want to switch to camelCase for your variables as that is standard in c. So instead of player_choice, you use playerChoice.

Comment: Please do not show pictures of plain text. Instead include it as formatted text. That holds true not only for code, but also for text input and output. Also, where did you get the idea that camelcase would be standard in C? There are tons of libraries around using different style.